# D.E: ${\large \frac{dx}{dt}}=(x-1)(1-2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know how can I prove that $t=\ln\left(\dfrac{2x-1}{x-1}\right)$ is the solution of the following Differential Equation:

$$\dfrac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t}=(x-1)(1-2x)$$

Comment: have you heard of differentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you differentiate $t(x) = \ln\left(\frac{2x-1}{x-1}\right)$, you will get the reciprocal right side (then think about a certain inverse function theorem..).

Comment: When i differentiate that, i get $-\dfrac{1}{(t-1)(2t-1)}$, what can i do whit the minus???

Comment: Yes but notice that you are differentiating $t$ with respect to $x$. How do $\frac{dt}{dx}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$ relate?

Comment: nice hints @CameronWilliams

Answer (score 1):

Invert your differential equation to give $$\frac {dt}{dx}=\frac 1{(x-1)(1-2x)}=-\frac1{x-1}-\frac 2{1-2x}$$ using partial fractions. Then integrate with respect to $x$ noting that you have standard integrals which give logarithms. Then consolidate the logarithms into a single expression.

Note that there is a constant of integration to take into account.